# How to stop PHP MySQLi from displaying warning message if db connection is failed?

Tags: php, mysqli

How can we stop PHP MySQLi from displaying ugly warning or error messages if the database connection is failed? We just want to display our own custom message instead.

Here's our code to make connection with db:

```
<?php
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "db_test";

$mysqli = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname);

if($mysqli->connect_error)
{
    die("Database connection failed: " . $mysqli->connect_error);
}

$mysqli->close();
?>
```

If the database "db_test" doesn't exist, we get the following error:

```
( ! ) Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1049): Unknown database 'db_test' in...
```

[image]

We just want to see this:

```
Database connection failed: Unknown database 'db_test'
```

What editing do I need to do in my above code?

**Note**

I know the database db_test doesn't exist. I am deliberately using wrong db just in order to see the warning or error message if any. I just want to see my custom error message if db connection failed (if it also fails in real scenario by any reason too) and not the warning generated from PHP.

**EDIT**

This warning message is only produced when I use OOP approach in MySQLi, and not with procedural.

Comment: can you post structure of your `DB`?

Comment: Because the warning is simple: db_test doesn't exist..

Comment: You should never display errors to users of your website/application as showing these would give insight to those who might want to hack your site. You can change the settings in the php.ini file or add `ini_set('display_errors', 0);` at the top of your page.

Comment: You are all overthinking unnecessarily. I don't need these suggestions. My query is totally different than that what you all guys are thinking.

Comment: oh now i see, you use Netbeans or Phpstorm true? have you try in live server?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini - I know warning is simple... but what I am asking you all, please re-read my question.

Comment: just see [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Comment: @SimoneRossaini [here] has no link.

Comment: @SimoneRossaini does it make any sense to talk about Netbeans or Phpstorm in reference to my question?

Comment: @JayBlanchard I know all these basic things. But my question is not about disabling PHP errors or warning messages. I just want to show my own error message. Also take care of OOP vs procedural approach as I said in my EDIT.

Comment: Then parse the error returned and display the bit which you want to show.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I already told you.

Comment: Yes because this structure error is from that program.

Comment: Using ini_set('display_errors', 0); to turn off mysqli warning messages is like repairing an engine making strange noises by turning it off. I think the need is to turn off the mysqli warning messages *only*. One might hope mysqli_report would do that, but alas, no.

Answer (score -2):

A simple approach to hide the warning message produced by PHP and to show only your own custom message is to use suppress operator (@).

Change line from

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname);
```

to

```
@$mysqli = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname);
```

Comment: the only problem, there should be not a single  die() statement

Comment: @YourCommonSense This was just a test file for making and testing db connection. It has nothing to do with a project. I don't understand why is this solution marked negative.

Comment: Because this solution is wrong and makes a bad example for the future readers. Hence naturally it is marked so.

Comment: Please note this solution is wrong for a test file as well. your files shouldn't really differ. A good code is good for either test or production.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Okay but I have read in several IT books written by famous authors that to suppress errors generated by MySQL or other functions, you should use @ operator. Are all they wrong?

Comment: Yes. Sadly, these authors are more famous than knowledgeable and their books are quite outdated. I don't really understand why did you dismiss the display_errors recommendation? It prevents all errors from displaying at once. Really handy. Not to mention the moment you need them displayed (on a test server) you just change one digit per whole project. Why going around adding @s and die()s when PHP can do it for you?

Comment: @YourCommonSense Oh! your statement is really very shocking. So you mean the authors of big publishers like Oreilly, Apress and Wrox, etc. are not that knowledgeable and skillful, right? If so then why they have been hired by these publishers? And not other guys like me, you and others? Also, you said their books are outdated but I'm not talking about their very old versions - they publish new editions time to time. And you know very well that the thing which is relevant today could easily become outdated in near future. You might have read their 90s or early 2Ks versions.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Besides these things, I know the stuff like `display_errors` etc. But my quest was different at that time.

Comment: Actually, such "new" editions are rather "facelifting" than real improvements. The notorious example is a Welling/Thomson book that has outdated/dangerous code all around.

Comment: Nobody question your knowledge. I am just curious why this function doesn't suit you in this particular case? It does solve your problem, in a much better way than @.